# БД на выделенном сервере

Tags: сервер, база-данных, mysql

Привет.

Есть необходимость вынести MySQL на DEDIC/VPS, логично, что производительность БД возрастет (будем считать, что DEDIC/VPS обладают довольно большими вычислительными ресурсами). Но как  насчет задержек в передаче данных? Если учитывать, что DEDIC/VPS c MySQL может находится у другого хостинг провайдера (может даже размещающегося в другой стране). Оставить Mysql на локалхост не предоставляется возможным. Насколько сильны будут задержки при передаче? И быть может существует какой-то другой, более правильный, вариант?

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

Дать исчерпывающий ответ на Ваш вопрос сможете только Вы сами. Во-первых необходимо определить причину, по которой возникла необходимость в переносе базы данных. Исходя из Вашего вопроса, могу предположить, что на данный момент база данных расположена на сервере хостинг провайдера. Хоcтинг провайдеры, как правило, выделяют под сервера баз данных достаточно мощные физические сервера, непосредственно настройка самого демона mysql выполняется специалистом, хорошо представляющим что он делает. В случае, если в работе Вашего приложения узким местом стала именно база (необходимо быть уверенным на 100% что, это именно база, а не, например, дисковая подсистема), для проверки скорости работы БД произведите диагностику скорости выполнения запросов, анализ запросов и структуры БД. В проведении диагностических мероприятий Вам могут быть полезны встроенные средства отладки Вашего приложения (debug mode) и такие утилиты, как [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/). В первую очередь обратите внимание на индексы и блокировки, используемый механизм хранения (storage engine). В случае, если с точки зрения приложения возможность оптимизации отсутствует, только в такой ситуации стоит рассматривать вариант переноса базы данных. Безусловно при размещении базы данных в другом датацентре будут издержки, связанные с сетевой подсистемой. Оправданность таких издержек можно оценить с помощью диагностических утилит, например [набор утилит, поставляемых вместе с mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-benchmarks.html) . Также в случае, если администрированием сервера баз данных будете заниматься Вы самостоятельно, изучите соответствующую литературу. Иначе даже на мощном выделенном сервере производительность базы данных может оказать хуже, чем на сервере хостинг провайдера. Для изучения могут быть полезны [официальная документация](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/) и книги. Среди русскоязычных изданий (в том числе переводов), на мой взгляд, лучшим является [MySQL. Оптимизация производительности.](http://www.books.ru/books/mysql-optimizatsiya-proizvoditelnosti-2-e-izdanie-734220/?show=1) Также в оптимизации настроек непосредственно демона mysql под работу именно Вашей базы может быть полезен скрипт [mysqltuner](https://raw.github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl). Использовать его без четкого понимания выполняемых Вами действий категорически не рекомендуется.

Comment: Cпасибо за исчерпывающий ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас имеется множество ДЦ в СНГ. При выборе ДЦ, расположенного неподалеку от Вас, задержка может не превышать 2-3 мс. У хостеров можно всегда узнать где они расположены, а также попросить IP адреса, для проверки удаленности сервера от Вас, и сразу можно увидеть задержку сетевого ответа. К примеру, задержка от Нидерландов или Германии ~50 мс, США - 130 (это из восточной Украины).